# Sum the values in selected rows of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
mylist = [{'Date': '01/02/2020', 'Value': '13'},
{'Date': '01/03/2020', 'Value': '2'},
{'Date': '10/3/2020', 'Value': '4'},
{'Date': '12/25/2020', 'Value': '2'}]
```

I wanted to sum the Values of the Date from 01/01/2020 to 01/04/2020. I tried the following to select the rows within the date range:

```
from datetime import datetime
dfmylist = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
dfmylist['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfmylist['Date']) 
dfmylistnew = (dfmylist['Date'] > '01/01/2020') & (dfmylist['Date'] <= '01/04/2020')
dfmylistnew1 = dfmylist.loc[dfmylistnew]
dfmylistnew1
```

I got the output data frame:

```
    Date    Value
0   2020-01-02  13
1   2020-01-03  2
```

I want to get the sum `Value` from the above data frame, which is 15

I tried:

```
total = dfmylistnew1['Value'].sum()
```

but the output is 132, instead of 15

Comment: Have you checked the dtype of `Value`? It seems that these are strings rather than integers. Hence `13 + 2 = 132`

Comment: `total = dfmylistnew1['Value'].astype(int).sum()` or `astype(float)`, it depends on your real values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your data, convert values with the right type:

```
mylist = [{'Date': '01/02/2020', 'Value': '13'},
          {'Date': '01/03/2020', 'Value': '2'},
          {'Date': '10/3/2020', 'Value': '4'},
          {'Date': '12/25/2020', 'Value': '2'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist).astype({'Date': 'datetime64', 'Value': 'int'})
total = df.loc[df['Date'].between('01/01/2020', '01/04/2020', inclusive='right'),
               'Value'].sum()
print(total)

# Output
15
```

Comment: Nice answer, and covers a potential issue he would have with the Date column as well :)